# Calling an Oracle function via Ajax for on-the-spot validation purposes in Oracle APEX v4.2.2

Tags: javascript, ajax, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am using Oracle 11g with Oracle Apex v4.2.2 and I was wondering how the best way to call an Oracle function via an ajax call, within a Dynamic Action.

I basically have a function that takes six parameters that either returns the result of 'INVALID' or 'VALID'.

Within my page, I want to be able to accept the values that the user has entered and once they press the button to process, I need to check via ajax whether the result was 'INVALID' or 'VALID' and immediately present the user with a dialog box notifying them that there was an error.

Is there a new means of processing this type of ajax request to call a function, within Oracle APEX v4.2.2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ajax + apex 4.2 = [apex.server.process api](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35127/javascript_api.htm#BGBIIJFC)
It requires you have a process at the on-demand process point of the page or an application process. In it you have to call your function and provide the parameters, which can be the page items. To provide a return, write values to the http buffer with calls to `htp.p`.

```
DECLARE
  some_var1 VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  some_var1 := my_package.my_function(:P1_EMPNO, :P1_DEPTNO);
  -- write values back
  htp.p(some_var1);
END;
```

You can easily provide `apex.server.process` with page items. Further handling is all in javascript.
Note of warning: the dataType is by default set to JSON, and thus if you provide no other default datatype and do not return a json string you will get a parsing error. So if you return a text within your on-demand process such as INVALID, make sure to set the datatype to text!

```
apex.server.process ( "MY_PROCESS", {
  pageItems: "#P1_DEPTNO,#P1_EMPNO"
  }, {
    dataType: "text"
  , success: function( pData ) { 
      //pData should contain VALID or INVALID - alert it
      alert(pData);
      if ( pData === 'INVALID' ) {
        // do something here when the result is invalid
        // maybe you want to color something red for example
        alert('The data you have entered is invalid');
      };
    }
  } );
```

I wouldn't split this up in more dynamic actions than necessary, even though it might be possible. I personally am not fond of trying to use a PLSQL block dynamic true action, just because it is more obscure to act on if you want to deal with return values.
Just set your button to not submit the page, but action defined by dynamic action. Then in the dynamic action create one true action of type execute javascript, and use the ajax call with callback(s) there.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks again for your reply but just have a few queries pls as I have never actually used apex.server.process: Q1) I am assuming the name of your on demand page process is called "MY_PROCESS". Q2) Does the pageItems ordering have to match the same order you have as the parameters within my_package.my_function(:P1_EMPNO, :P1_DEPTNO) as based on your example above, this doesn't seem to be the case? Q3) Sorry, I didn't fully understand your true action point - your last sentence above. Could you please elaborate on this and do I also need to have a FALSE action as well? Thanks Tom.

Comment: 1) Yes, that is correct, the names have to match! 2) The order matters not at all. It is simply to set the value of those items in session state so they're available in your process 3) To make the ajax call by pressing your button, I suppose that using a dynamic action to react on click of that button to be the easiest. The dynamic action would then have one true action of the type 'execute javascript', and in that action you would perform the ajax call.

Comment: Hey Tom, really not sure what is going on but it looks like my on demand page process is being called from apex.server.process as I have a insert statement with commit providing me the result. But the thing is, the actual apex.server.process success section is not returning any alerts - specifically alert(pData) is not even showing anything or not firing. I don't think the htp.p is working. Is there anyway in Chrome inspector to see actual result? Not sure if I have missed anyting. Thanks.

Comment: The best way to debug is to open up the Network tab in the dev tools of chrome (remember: it has to be open in order to capture network calls). Let the page load, clear the calls. Then click your button (or whatever triggers the ajax call) and inspect the newly added line (will be to wwv_flow.show). Check the response headers: anything in there? Are there any javascript errors being reported? You can see those from the console tab in the dev tools.

Comment: No javascript errors but I have no idea what I am looking for exactly in the headers. Do I look for the on demand process name?

Comment: Hi Tom, decided to run it in both Firefox and IE8 browsers and alerts seem to work there, so all good. Not sure what's going on with Chrome - completely ignored alerts.

Comment: You could try to see a result in chrome by using `apex.debug(...)`. This is a wrapper for `console.log(..)` but will not cause an error in ie8 (console.log gives a js error in ie8 unless dev tools are open)