# How to perform row by row validation on an Oracle APEX Tabular form using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oracle11g, oracle-apex

Using the same validation/processing that I performed, based on this thread:

[Calling an Oracle Function via Ajax for on the spot Validation Purposes in Oracle APEX v4.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474303/calling-an-oracle-function-via-ajax-for-on-the-spot-validation-purposes-in-oracl)

I now have a tabular form that can have 1 to n rows but when the user presses the "Apply" button, I need to perform this same type of validation, that I have, based on the thread above, i.e.:

An example set of rows might be like:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
----------------------------
A       10      20      30
B       5       8       9
C       92      88      12
D       1       2       44
E       95      77      88
```

Based on the above scenario, when the user presses the "Apply" button, via a Dynamic Action/Ajax (apex.server.process) call, I need to iterate through each row, using the above four columns (no checkboxes used here, just select lists, to select column values), call my
ajax process to check whether:

```
(Col2 > Col4) for all rows
```

and if so, return via javascript, an alert message to the user indicating that a problem was found with the data (i.e. INVALID response from apex.server.process).

I basically need to check this validation for all rows, prior to committing records to the database.

Ideally I would like to solve this via DA/Ajax/jQuery.

Comment: This question may help in this case:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39274196/oracle-apex-validate-tabular-form-row-by-row

Answer (score 1):

How I would try to solve it. Note that this doesn't cover all (any?) eventuality or much error handling. You'll have to elaborate on it a bit yourself. eg I used input for a selector, you'll need "select". The arrays may not match. You may need a completely other selector such as by td[headers]. Maybe your return object will need to hold other or more values. Your js may need more expanding upon.
Nevertheless it should provide you with a good base to start from!

Javascript:

```
function validaterows(){
  var arrf01 = [], arrf02 = [];

  //fetch all the values from the source columns and put them in
  //a javascript array.
  $("input[name=f03]").each(function(){
    arrf01.push($v(this));
  });

  $("input[name=f04]").each(function(){
    arrf02.push($v(this));
  });

  //provide the constructed arrays to the on-demand process by using
  //the global f## arrays
  apex.server.process ( "MY_PROCESS", {
      f01: arrf01
    , f02: arrf02
  }, {
  , success: function( pData ) { 
      //pData should be an object, because jquery will have parsed the returned json-string
      apex.debug(pData);

      $.each(pData.validationArray, function(index, value){
        if ( value === 'INVALID' ) {
          // do something here when the result is invalid
          // maybe you want to color something red for example
          alert('The data at row '+index+' is not valid!');
        };
      });

      }
  } );
}
```

On-demand plsql process:

```
DECLARE
  l_return VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN apex_application.g_f01.count
  LOOP
    -- remember: the f## arrays are varchar arrays. Important for comparisons.
    -- Also take into account that the values could NOT be numeric at all.
    -- you'll probably want to run each value through an is-number check or else 
    -- you'll run into ORA errors
    IF to_number(apex_application.g_f01(i)) > to_number(apex_application.g_f02(i))
    THEN
      l_return := l_return || ',"INVALID"';
    ELSE
      l_return := l_return || ',"VALID"';
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  IF l_return IS NOT NULL
  THEN
    -- create a json string 
    -- holds an object with 1 property (validationArray) with the value being
    -- an array holding a value for each row submitted
    l_return := '{"validationArray":['||LTRIM(l_return, ',')||']}';
  END IF;

  -- write the output to the buffer
  htp.p(l_return);
END;
```

Comment: All worked great. Have a few queries pls: 1) Within your validaterows() function above, instead of showing the user which index row is invalid, how could I actually show the value in Col1 above instead (i.e. "A,B,C,D or E") - assuming that this column/cell is just a display value column that has the definition of $("td[headers='COL1'") ? 2) I am actually looking at using the jQueryUI dialog, to present the user this error message, instead of an  alert - the only problem I have is, if I am issuing a $('#dialogbox').dialog('open'), how can I pass a parameter to it, say Col1 value? Thanks.

Comment: 1) You could tackle it in various ways. Perhaps most straightforward is to get the row by using said index in a jquery selector, using `:eq()` or `.eq()` on the `tr` elements and looking at the item holding that unique value within that row. Another could be to only return invalid rows in the validation, and providing the uk value to the validation process so it can also return the matching ones (you'd have to return objects though). 2) You don't provide params to the dialog as it pops up an html element. Set the value of a eg a span element prior to opening the dialog.

Comment: Thanks Tom - I will try that. At the moment, trying to work out how to pass the index row for invalid row(s) into a jQuery UI dialog, similar to your alert above but instead using a jQuery UI dialog with an "OK" button. Any ideas on this? Thanks.

Comment: Yes - it's in the previous comment :) Make your #dialogbox html generic enough so that you can easily set the value of an element in it. Eg using a span you can easily target that element and set the text value of it to the id (or whatever). Then, open the dialog, which takes the #dialogbox element and pops it out for display.

Comment: No worries Tom. Sorry - missed that bit in your previous comment. Thanks.