# How to overlay a jQuery UI Dialog over a Skillbuilders modal page?

Tags: jquery-ui, oracle11g, modal-dialog, oracle-apex

I am using the SkillBuilders Modal Page within my Oracle APEX application, i.e.

[SkillBuilders Modal Page](http://www.apex-plugin.com/oracle-apex-plugins/dynamic-action-plugin/skillbuilders-modal-page_138.html)

to present the user with a tabular form, where they can enter specific values via select lists.

What I also have is validation based on another thread that I raised in Stackoverflow:

[How to perform row by row validation on an Oracle APEX Tabular form using Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570464/how-to-perform-row-by-row-validation-on-an-oracle-apex-tabular-form-using-ajax)

The problem that I am having is within my SkillBuilders Modal Page, I have some validation by where I want to make a call to jQueryUI dialog, in order to present the user a message. I do this by calling:

```
$('#dialogbox').dialog('open');
```

Unfortunately it doesn't actually seem to appear on screen and I believe it's something to do with the fact that I am trying to overlay a modal dialog over a modal page (skillbuilders modal plugin).

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you initialised the dialog before you call `dialog('open')`?

Comment: Do you mean in document.ready() - if so, then yes. Is there a specific setting I need to set for a modal on modal setup?

Comment: Do you want to overlay the dialog over the modal page, or do you want to open the dialog modally within the the modal page? The dialogbox element is present on the modal page?

Comment: Hi Tom, it's the latter of your question, i.e. "or do you want to open the dialog modaly within the the modal page?" It was this, I was having trouble with but tracked down this link which has solved my problem: https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/issues/248

Comment: Managed to solve this problem based on this link: https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/issues/248

Comment: A link-only answer below [offers this link](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox/issues/248). The Review Queue may delete the answer unless it is expanded, since link-only answers are not considered substantial enough for Stack Overflow, and they are subject to periodic breakage.