# Dynamically add rows to existing table

Tags: html

I have the table with 100 records
at the first time the page loading i want to display only 10 records and the more link
if the link is clicked display 10 more records the records are populated from the oracle database. I don't know how to use the oracle contents in javascript or ajax .

Please Reply .

Answer (score 2):

You could try it in jquery more or less like this

```
$("#tableID").find('tbody')
    .append($('<tr>')
        .append($('<td>')

        )
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use DataTables.

It handles the client side displaying of the Data. There you have to implement the server side logic. Further it comes with pagination and searching.

https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Answer (score 1):

```
   $('table > tbody:last').append('<tr><td>...</td></tr>');
```

Jquery my way to  append a row dynamically.

Comment: Put the above code in a for loop for 10 records. then repopulate

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [Calling an Oracle Function via Ajax for on the spot Validation Purposes in Oracle APEX v4.2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474303/calling-an-oracle-function-via-ajax-for-on-the-spot-validation-purposes-in-oracl) If you can call oracle function with ajax then it should be easy to have your required changes.
 if you have any other scripting language involved in server side then you'll get lot's of different ways